# How to leave space for missing values in a dodged bar chart

Tags: vega

In a Vega dodged bar chart, when a category is missing values, the remaining bars stretch to fill the empty space… is there a way to make it leave space for the missing bars instead?

[Example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgBY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwAZgAMuxREgpG1fFoBMog0siF0atYxnUtAVkW216PJhwBtJQhQCFCoGXRUZC1IX3YAG2jDMKgKdHjWZFgtQJTQ4Eh4HxpuACcAT2xIAEEFKEJuWGYeOSwDVPTM7F06AEYAX2S8gqK8Eoqq2vl6xubZbF7pyDSM6La6ADZBoJSR4uoyyqxIACE6u1m8FuwLJZWurF6+7bzgwv3DqrOlhqar+aw2junTWPQAHC9XnsxgcJscAMLnX5zVrtZYg7qbSHDd4wz4IpGXa6PYGrTEDIa7XHjI6QRE-IkA24dMnrCzYqmjGlVekzP7EoEsh49ADs-R2EAAujtxVLPEYEOksjkdiEUpAIlEYuVFYkFBKoHhyoQ1lB2OgZGp9XlIGpuBhnFoCt5fDE4nqlgAzRjIeJWnDU2GVDlGUoW6im4zIUzmSlGeyOZyuHA9CwyylqsIayKRgAeuqSBtixsj8WcyHQpWt6rtDtaYGdPj8hvQCSSUG9vv9QuiIagYZckdUGkQ1azpW4rEtWjwpUycagAC9kBOZ3PkAuNYx4KbZ5l06qi5rI-BuPEymPQsWTTEyk4IvFL0Za+hHThG66A+725BO36Ysi-xyH2kADhGTqQPwaAnh8FQWLokCyqESGSvKUDoLmyoBKqkBlD6Mh4DEiSeoRSwFtq5FLFc8AANYAMqMMuWhovEra+gACg497JmAohLIuzhqMguZaBSOF4cgBExOw3AEPa5zkQG+ZFHqKFoZAGClDR2TYWEmZXkaN4BtQE6sIQ+pFp6E6oE6BpGJ66A7oR752VeLrNrErYeq5RjHjEDlOU+6omZOhDsEcUBckGkCuUhYTbEWkmnkJtmvFAkljFWLlpUYEUFIpUA6ipP5-t2gafHFKSVRACU2k01APjpYC5FC2ZagGJhmKRUBmS6kbmpaw4sAAFAA5EVSqjQAlIhBqoSARYFk1LXDD54Q5gBjRBVmhn9RaVoLuO4aRp1sZrba9qvvWH4eQFyDdb+Pr-gGgHXNVyFzWhWaadpKppfpNp+QG5qlNkh1XlZ8nvraTb+Y592IeDRi7TEpTIPApHnUl3ApdlOVGBlK6pfjV55ZBxWbWDHZPWVr3zH2aVRjGzkNuTSqU+cA3dmJJNXiJ0MFZAyns16NMxPcvZI+quYWBBgvCx6PbMQzryPfEj4CxTAanueVai12lMorNvPvfFsXgwD6oo1+wmY-jv7WRB7nSZW2QqwTMjJaals2oTWUNmtWb86zpUxDL5zcJ6nqwAjOAALRuO76pk6HAaVEskfR7HIdix10ZdecqCsPELM9InSdZt66sQRLMTKIgzCS4HV7pKY13oqy-bM4jzdGOaMdljI3sdw8UCoOoaiqVLO22xBqdQC6rCoHQtem1Va1r+90pm1KIDikAA):

[image]

What I want it to look like:

[image]

Specifically, I'm looking for a way to accomplish this by modifying the spec without modifying the data directly. The [impute transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/impute/) looks promising, but I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the `pos` scale in the inner scope, you should put it in the outer scope, so there is only one shared scale across the plots.

[image]

[Example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgBY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwAZgAMuxREgpG1fFoBMog0siF0atYxnUtAVkW216PJhwBtJQhQCFCoGXRUZC1IX3YAG2jDMKgKdHjWZFgtQJTQ4Eh4HxpuACcAT2xIAEEFKEJuWGYeOSwDVPTM7F06AEYAX2S8gqK8Eoqq2vl6xubZbF7pyDSM6La6ADZBoJSR4uoyyqxIACE6u1m8FuwLJZWurF6+7bzgwv3DqrOlhqar+aw2junTWPQAHC9XnsxgcJscAMLnX5zVrtZYg7qbSHDd4wz4IpGXa6PYGrTEDIa7XHjI6QRE-IkA24dMnrCzYqmjGlVekzP7EoEsh49ADs-R2EAAujtxVLPEYEOksjkdiEUpAIlEYuVFYkFBKoHhyoQ1lB2OgZGp9XlIGpuBhnFoCt5fDE4nqlgAzRjIeJWnDU2GVDlGUoW6im4zIUzmSlGeyOZyuHA9CwyylqsIayKRgAeuqSBtixsj8WcyHQpWt6rtDtaYGdPj8hvQCSSUG9vv9QuiIagYZckdUGkQ1azpW4rEtWjwpUycagAC9kBOZ3PkAuNYx4KbZ5l06qi5rI-BuPEymPQsWTTEyk4IvFL0Za+hHThG66A+725BO36Ysi-xyH2kADhGTqQPwaAnh8FQWLokCyqEHKZlex4AY0T6GiWMTmtOm5gaa-jtAUTTUA+uEWmow4sAAFAA5DqRSJPRACUiGSpuL5vg2tpNm6rYeh2Pr-gGgHXEhEBIZxIC2OgubKgEqqQGUPoyHgMSJJ6GlLAW2p6UsVzwAA1gAyowy5aGi8Str6AAKDj3smYCiEsi7OGoyC5loFLKapyDqbh3AEPa5x6QG+bMb2SgybYGClMZ2RKWEqFGEaN4BtQE6sIQ+pFp6E6oE6BpGJ66A7hp74lVeLrNrEgmFq8aE5jEZUVVhWZZZOhDsEcUBckGkDVZJyHyuqAWnp5xVNZAAVjFWVVNUYfWkVF+lrV6IndoGnwjWEe1gNsRbxYlKpNal6roQG5qlNkC5ZgVoXvnxn4duVyAaX2WbpZGpTIPAOnVUYE3cFNi1LcD6krtNENXitkFrWJmGbV2GH8vMX2vFGMaVbx4V8uceHdr5sNXt5z345AkVKucf7bfcvb3VjuYWBBlPU0J6KsmAuiYza3rxI+FOI-1Z4Xijol8iiiFA8hssHVJTMXd9OFfl5gMQ7+hUQbVlG3YhTOQ5NprK+NUMLQ2stZuTvF0zELPnNwnqerAH1aAAtG4fPqvDdsBpUSxOy7bvPX7uDRmYOlQKgrDxLjPRe97D2MILEEMzEyiIMwjNW1e6SmPWBTpwGpQ4wbudGOartljIJtcw80fqGoepJ1eYy5rjBRhy9rCoHQ6cKykg9ScNBrSvtMUgOKQA)